# How to get the selected value of MS Drop-down list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have used MS Dropdown list in my MVC Project. Now I want to get the MS Dropdownvalue using Jquery. How can achieve that?

```
$("#Country").msDropdown();
```

I want to get the selected value of INDIA using JQuery.

`var countryName = $("#Country option:selected").val();`

It does not seem to be working.

Comment: Inspect generated HTML, it should help. That plugin creates unordered list (probably), so you can't target values like in ordinary dropdown... and, i believe that in plugin documentation - you have described way to get selected value?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var countryName = $("#Country option:selected").text();
```

instead of

```
var countryName = $("#Country option:selected").val();
```